# NullPointerException with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, lifecycle

My application contains ViewPager in MainActivity with two fragments. First fragment contains ListView. I never see this, but I see reports from users about RuntimeException in Google Play:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.my.project/com.my.project.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.my.project/com.my.project.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2120)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1668)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.my.project/com.my.project.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2107)
 ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.my.project.FirstFragment.load(FirstFragment.java:551)
 at com.my.project.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:132)
 at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2528)
 ... 13 more
```

Here is code from FirstFragment.java:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<ListItemObject> listItems = null;
    ArrayAdapter<ListItemObject> mAdapter;

    void load() {
            mAdapter.clear(); // I get error here, that is FirstFragment.java:551
            ...
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        listItems = new ArrayList<ListItemObject>();
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), listItems);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

}
```

That is all occuerences of mAdapter. And I can't understand, how it can cause NullPointerException. I think that sometimes Fragment1 destroying and recreating, but without onCreateView(). **I talk with one of users which have this problem and he say me, that this bug run away after he uncheck "Don't keep activities" in "Developer options" in settings.** I don't know, can I fix it? Or I need to say all my users "uncheck this option"?

In my NainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    Vector<Fragment> fragments;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment1.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment2.class.getName()));

        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(fragments.size());
        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode==1) {
            ((MainChat)fragments.get(0)).load();
        }
    }

    class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter {

        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragments.size();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's your `MainActivity`? The error clearly states there is something going on at `MainActivity::onActivityResult`, which you apparently do not have...

Comment: When load() is called? Probably mAdapter is not persisting through config changes.

Comment: You certainly do not need to have user change their device options, you have to **fix** this issue... Which is probably the result of a known issue in the _Support Package_, but without further information we can only guess.

Comment: @K-ballo, sorry, I forgot it. I edit my question and add onActivityResult().

Comment: @JoãoMelo, load called in onActivityResult(). But this exception occuring infrequently.

Comment: Post line 551 of your FirstFragment class and line 132 of your MainActivity..LogCat is telling you that these lines are your problemCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.my.project.FirstFragment.load(FirstFragment.java:551)
 at com.my.project.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:132)

Comment: @JadeByfield, 551: mAdapter.clear(); and 132: ((MainChat)fragments.get(0)).load();

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason of the error is that your MainActivity was destroyed and then being recreated by Android OS.

That means fragments list will be created again in your MainActivity.onCreate() method, but PagerAdapter will not use those fragments, instead it will use instances of fragments that was restored for you by FragmentManager (e.g. PagerAdapter.getItem() will not be called). And since instance of FirstFragment from your fragments list is not used it will not receive a call to FirstFragment.onCreateView() and mAdapter instance will stil be null then you'll call FirstFragment.load() method.

The easiest (but not very good) way to fix this issue is to suppress restoring of your fragments by passing null as savedInstanceState param in MainActivity.onCreate():

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null);
    ...
}
```

Another way to go is to create fragments in your PagerAdapter on demand:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0: return Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment1.class.getName());
        case 1: return Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment2.class.getName());
        default: throw new RuntimException();
    }
}
```

and storing instances of fragments this way:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
    Fragment fr = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    fragments[position] = fr;
    return fr;
}
```

(Note: second way was not tested by me, so it may not work)

BTW, you can check "Don't keep activities" developer option in your Android 4.0 settings to test such issues.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that the activity containing the fragments has been disposed of. This can happen at any time while the activity is not being displayed - what your user did was change a developer setting which aggressively destroys activities to allow you to see coding issues like this one. The problem can still happen, and the fewer resources a device has available (either because it has little memory, or because a lot of other things are running), the more often Android will do this.

Having explained the background to the underlying issue, lets move on to the specific problem in your `onActivityResult()` code. This method is invoked at a point in the view lifecycle before the context around your fragments and activity has been reconstituted, so you can't do any meaningful work with your fragments in this method and be sure it will always work. Instead save the response in a class level variable and use it in `onResume()` which will be called whether the activity was destroyed or not.

As an aside, you should move the `onActivityResult()` method into the fragment - and always invoke `super.onActivityResult()` before your own code.

Finally note that Android destroys and recreates fragments at its own whim (for example, when you rotate your device, all your fragments are destroyed and re-created). Therefore you should ensure you understand and work with the Activity and Fragment lifecycles, and not against them as Alex's solution suggests. This will only lead to other difficult to diagnose problems.